# Django - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a Django app that will parse the contents of an uploaded log file to the associated database in my Django project. I've managed to get it all running as expected except it won't associate my uploaded data with the model's ForeignKey. I can assign null=True which resolves the integrity error but then of course, it doesn't assign any of the uploaded data to that ForeignKey. Here's the code:

models.py

```
class Case(models.Model):

    case_ref = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    oic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitted_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('case_list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.case_ref + " " + self.subject
    
class TeamviewerLogs(models.Model):
    
        case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) 
        teamviewer_id = models.IntegerField()
        teamviewer_name = models.TextField()
        connection_start = models.TextField()
        connection_end = models.TextField()
        local_user = models.TextField()
        connection_type = models.TextField()
        unique_id = models.TextField()
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('case_list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.teamviewer_id) + " - " + str(self.teamviewer_id)
```

forms.py

```
class UploadLog(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField()
    
    class Meta:
      model = TeamviewerLogs
      fields = [
        'file'
      ]
```

views.py

```
def add_logs(request, pk):
  case = get_object_or_404(Case, pk=pk)

  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = UploadLog(request.POST, request.FILES)
      
      if form.is_valid():
          teamviewer = form.save(commit=False)
          teamviewer.case = case


          log_file = request.FILES['file']
          log_file = filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in log_file))

          for lines in log_file:

              split = lines.decode('utf-8').split('\t')

              teamviewer_id = split[0]
              teamviewer_name = split[1]
              connection_start = split[2]
              connection_end = split[3]
              local_user = split[4]
              connection_type = split[5]
              unique_id = split[6]
          


              teamviewer = TeamviewerLogs(teamviewer_id=teamviewer_id, teamviewer_name=teamviewer_name, 
                                        connection_start=connection_start, connection_end=connection_end, 
                                        local_user=local_user, connection_type=connection_type, unique_id=unique_id)

              teamviewer.save()
              return redirect('tv_log_details', pk=case.pk)
      form.save()

  else:
      form = UploadLog()

  return render(request, 'teamviewer/add_logs.html', {'form': form})
```

But when I click to upload the file I'm hit with:
[image]

When it tries to execute teamviewer.save().

I've been trying to resolve this issue for hours and have tried so many different variations of answers from Stackoverflow or previous code I've used that has worked for different models but I've hit a brick wall...hard!

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `TeamviewerLogs(case=case, ....)`? It's null because you don't assign it anywhere...

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you I'd tried that a while back and was still hit with an error! But I've just tried it again and is worked without error! Thank you for taking the time to respond. Much appreciated

Comment: Pass the case to the form's initial data, with the case field hidden that way it'll have a value. You can then check it's not been changed in the `clean_case` method before it's saved.

Comment: Hi @markwalker_, this is actually what I've been trying to figure out but couldn't understand the best way of doing it. Would you care to share how you think would be the best way to achieve this? Or provide a link to some reading material? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's an example of the concept I've suggested in the comments.

I've got a view which passes some data to the a form;

```py
class ListingDetailView(DetailView):
    """ Listing detail page """
    model = Listing
    template_name = 'listing.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """Return the kwargs for the form"""
        kwargs = {}
        initial = {
            'listing': self.object,
        }

        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        return kwargs

    def get_form(self):
        form = ApplicationSignupForm(
            **self.get_form_kwargs()
        )
        return form

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Add our form to the context """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context
```

The form then makes use of that initial data and sets the field it relates to as hidden. I don't validate this data, but I'll try to show how you might do that;

```py
class ApplicationSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        """ Setup the form """
        fields = (
            'listing',
            ...
        )
        model = Application
        widgets = {
            'listing': forms.HiddenInput()
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        initial_data = kwargs['initial']
        self.listing = initial_data.get('listing')
        

    def clean(self):
        """
        Custom form cleaning
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        listing = cleaned_data.get('listing')
        if listing != self.listing:
            self.add_error('listing', "You can't modify this value")

        return cleaned_data
```